# Semantics of adding an Object and an integer to each other, in PHP?

Tags: php, object, type-conversion, duck-typing

```
class wat
{
   public $a = 3.14;
   public $x = 9;
   public $y = 2;
}


$a = new wat();

var_dump(1000 + $a);
var_dump($a + 1000);
```

The output is:

```
int(1001)
int(1001)
```

Well, adding the [wat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0)<sup>*</sup> object to an integer is obviously not the right thing to do, since PHP complains about it with *"Object of class wat could not be converted to int"*, but still, what does it do?

(I also have a practical reason for asking this, I want to refactor a function to get rid of the "PHP Notice", while still keeping behaviour completely unchanged.)

---

*: [http://img.youtube.com/vi/kXEgk1Hdze0/1.jpg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0)

Comment: reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addition (`+`) implicitly casts both operands to `float` if either one of them is `float`, otherwise both operands are cast to `int` ([See paragraph #2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).)

It seems that, at least for now, an `object` cast to `int` results in the value `1`, hence the result `1000 + 1 = 1001` or `1 + 1000 = 1001`, however, [per the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting), the behavior is undefined and should not be relied upon.

If you've turned on `E_NOTICE` error reporting, a notice should also be produced, saying that object could not be converted to int.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you shouldn't cast an Object to an Integer and you can't!
Than's why PHP assigns the integer 1 to the variable and should give you a notice which looks like this:

```
Notice: Object of class foo could not be converted to int in /path/to/file.php on line 1
$foo is now 1
int(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

to be sure I get the code which actually do the cast:

from Zend/zend_operators.c:

```
case IS_OBJECT:
    {
    int retval = 1;
        /* some other code */
        ZVAL_LONG(op, retval);  // < This sets the 1 you see.
        return;
    }
```

so it is not like i said before a internal cast ((int)(boolean)$object)
by doing this they preserve semantics of 0,"",NULL,false = false and !0,"...",Object = true

Comment: `boolean` doesn't figure in the type casting here, in this case addition casts the object to `int` which results in **1** but it is undefined behavior.

Comment: your are right that the implicit cast is not to boolean and that the behavior is undefined, but it seems that php acctually do something like (int)((boolean)($object)) which will result always in int(1). while this is not documented and specified behavior can change in later versions

Comment: (int)$object also results in int(1) (as of PHP 5.3 and 5.4)